# c# Print rows from array that only contain positive integers

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop, console

I'm really close ,but I just can't seem to wrap my head around the last step.
So what I want is to have 2d matrix and print only the rows that have ALL positive ints.

Right now my code is just taking out the ints that are either 0 or negative,but I need to remove the entire line if said line contains a 0 or negative.

This is what I'm getting right now

Input:

```
1 2 6 4

1 5 0 9
```

Output:

```
1 2 6 4

1 5
```

So basically it should not have printed the 2nd row b/c it had a non positive integer

What am I doing wrong?

I appreciate you taking the time to give this a look over!

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
// reads in multiples lines( array from console)            
List<string> L = readAllLines();

            // feeds read lines into matrix
            int[,] m = convertListToIntMatrix(L);// feeds read lines into matrix

            int Rows = m.GetLength(0);
            int Cols = m.GetLength(1);

            for (int r = 0; r < Rows; r++)
            {
                for (int c = 0; c < Cols; c++)
                {

                    if (m[r, c] <= 0)
                    {

                        break;

                    }
                    else Console.Write("{0} ", m[r, c]);
                }
                Console.WriteLine();

            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your loop to something like this:

```
for (int r = 0; r < Rows; r++)
{
    bool rowOkay = true;
    for (int c = 0; c < Cols; c++)
    {
        if (m[r, c] <= 0)
        {
            rowOkay = false;
        }
    }
    if (rowOkay)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<Cols;++i) {Console.Write("{0} ", m[r,i]);}
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You break when you find the 0 but you output everything before. Instead you could set a flag and later evaluate it to output the row if the flag is not set. You would still break but defer all output until you know the row is good.

Answer (score 0):

Are you in Jim Harris' PP2 class by any chance? You could also set a variable to count how many positive numbers there were in the row and if it equals the number or integers in the row then print the row out.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using list collection, just check Min() value of the list;

```
list1.Min() <= 0
```